# ubuntu server Execute python script via crontab

Tags: server, scripts, python, cron

I am trying to run a python script on a server with Ubuntu but it does not work. I manually tested the script and it WORKS correctly but I automatically tested it in 3 ways but nothing;

1. `1 * * * * /location/of/script/1.py`
   (With execute permission and `#!/usr/bin/python` in the file)
2. `1 * * * * python /location/of/script/1.py`
3. `1 * * * * /usr/bin/python /location/of/script/1.py`

Enable the `cron` log and "run it" and it doesn't give me any errors. But the file must backup images and upload to another server but it does not.

Comment: isn't it `#!/usr/bin/env python` instead of `#!/Usr/bin/python`?

Comment: I tried both and neither works

Answer (score 0):

Your test environment ("manually tested the script") and the `cron` environment differ in many ways. Some of these differences cause your `python` script to fail (I hope you meant `#!/usr/bin/python`, Case Counts!).

Add this to your `crontab` for a couple of minutes, then remove it:

```
*  *  *   *   *     (echo "=== set ===";set;echo "===env ==="; env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias) >cron.environment
```

Also, in your test envionment, do:

```
echo "=== set ===";set;echo "===env ==="; env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias) >test.environment
```

Read/diff each file (`less {cron,test}.environment;diff {cron,test}.environment`).

Read `man 5 crontab` to see how to alter `cron`'s environment.

Remember, `cron` isn't `bash`, but bash wrapper scripts make up fo that.

Comment: add the two lines in crontab and less {cron,test}.environment; "cron.environment: No such file or directory
test.environment: No such file or directory"

Comment: Please follow the instructions in th answer. Only add first line to `crontab`, wait until it executes (and creates `cron.environment`). Execute the second line in the same environment where your script "works".

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem doing this:

```
01 * * * * cd /home/user/folder && /usr/bin/python 1.py
```